# LARAVEL Insert MULTIPLE ROWS in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert multiple row data in two DB tables using single click but this code insert only one row at a time. When i try dd($request->all()); i got data in array but insert only one row. What is the problem and how can i fix it?

protected $table = 'biniyojan';

////Modified Controller//////

```
public function bbcreate(Request $request)
{

    //dd($request->all());
    $biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();


    $biniyojan = new Biniyojan();
    $biniyojan->details_id = $biniyojan_details->details_id;
    $biniyojan->date =  $request->date;
    $biniyojan->ab =  $request->ab;
    $biniyojan->school =  $request->school;
    $biniyojan->behora =  $request->behora;
    $biniyojan->save();


    $biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();
    if (!empty($request->school)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count((array)$request->school); $i++) {
        $biniyojan_details['biniyojan_id'] = $biniyojan->id;
        $biniyojan_details['school'] = $request->school[$i];
        $biniyojan_details['source'] = $request->source[$i];
        $biniyojan_details['kriyakalap'] = $request->kriyakalap[$i];
        //$biniyojan_details->debit_credit = $request->debit_credit[$i];
        //$biniyojan_details->debit_credit_type = $request->debit_credit_type[$i];
        $biniyojan_details['cash'] = $request->cash[$i];
        $biniyojan_details->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Inserted');
}
```

/////View Blade////////

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('bbcreate') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-row col-x1-3">
        <div class="form-group     col-md-2">
            <input type="date" placeholder="मिति" value="@php echo $today; @endphp" name="date" class="form-control" id="inputCity" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <select id="inputState" placeholder="" name="ab" class="form-control" required>
                <option>2079-080</option>
                <option>2078-079</option>
            </select>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group     col-md-2">
            <select id="inputState" name="school" class="form-control" required>
                <option selected disabled>स्रोत पाउने संस्था </option>
                @foreach ($school_array as $sch)
                <option value="{{ $sch -> name }}">{{ $sch -> name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="form-field">
        <div class="form-row col-x1-3">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select id="source" name="source[]" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">स्रोत</option>
                    <option>केन्द्र</option>
                    <option>प्रदेश</option>
                    <option>स्थानीय</option>
                    <option>अन्य</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select id="kriyakalap" name="kriyakalap[]" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled>क्रियाकलाप</option>
                    @foreach ($bini as $bi)
                    <option value="{{$bi->kriyakalap}}"> {{$bi->kriyakalap}}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>
                @foreach ($bini as $bi)

                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select name="debit_credit[]" id="debit_credit" class="form-control" >
                    <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select name="debit_credit_type[]" id="debit_credit_type" class="form-control" >
                    <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट प्रकार</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="रकम" name="cash[]" class="form-control" id="price" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add" id="add" value="+">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row col-x1-3" style="justify-content:left ;">
        <div class="form-group     col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ब्यहोरा" name="behora" class="form-control" id="behora" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="राख्नुहोस्" class="btn btn-primary ">

        </div>

        @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
            {{-- message --}}
        {!! Toastr::message() !!}
        </div>
        @endif

    </div>
    <div form-row col-x1-3 id="showdata" class="showdata">
        <p class="show_data"></p>
        <p id="showdata" class="showdata"></p>
    </div>
</form>


//////jQuery For Repeat form////////[enter image description here][1]
<!-- form repeat -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var html = '<span><div id="form-field"> <div class="form-row col-x1-3"> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select id="source" name="source[]" class="form-control" required> <option selected disabled value="">स्रोत</option> <option>केन्द्र</option> <option>प्रदेश</option> <option>स्थानीय</option> <option>अन्य</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select id="kriyakalap" name="kriyakalap[]" class="form-control" required> <option selected disabled>क्रियाकलाप</option> @foreach ($bini as $bi) <option value="{{$bi->kriyakalap}}"> {{$bi->kriyakalap}}</option> @endforeach </select> @foreach ($bini as $bi) @endforeach </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select name="debit_credit[]" id="debit_credit" class="form-control" required> <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select name="debit_credit_type[]" id="debit_credit_type" class="form-control" required> <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट प्रकार</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <input type="text" placeholder="रकम" name="cash[]" class="form-control" id="price" required> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="remove" id="remove" value="-"> </div> </div> </div></span>';
        var max = 5;
        var x = 1;
        $("#add").click(function() {
            if (x <= max) {
                $("#form-field").append(html);
                x++;
            }
        })
        $("#form-field").on('click', '#remove', function() {
            $(this).closest('span').remove();
            x--;
        });
    });

</script>

<!-- form repeat -->
```

Comment: Move `$biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();` inside of your loop, otherwise you're going to be overwriting the details of the first object each time.

Comment: I have tried but didn't work. It also send only one details at a time

Answer (score 0):

As @aynber pointed at, you need to move the line `$biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();` inside the loop so it initiate a new object for each iteration.

Another solution would be to insert all the entries in the same time(better performance). For that, we prepare the data to be inserted first

```
public function bbcreate(Request $request)
{

    //dd($request->all());
    $biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();


    $biniyojan = new Biniyojan();
    $biniyojan->details_id = $biniyojan_details->details_id;
    $biniyojan->date =  $request->date;
    $biniyojan->ab =  $request->ab;
    $biniyojan->school =  $request->school;
    $biniyojan->behora =  $request->behora;
    $biniyojan->save();


    $biniyojanDetailsToBeInserted = [];
    if (!empty($request->school)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count((array)$request->school); $i++) {
            $biniyojan_details = [];
            $biniyojan_details['biniyojan_id'] = $biniyojan->id;
            $biniyojan_details['school'] = $request->school[$i];
            $biniyojan_details['source'] = $request->source[$i];
            $biniyojan_details['kriyakalap'] = $request->kriyakalap[$i];
            //$biniyojan_details['debit_credit'] = $request->debit_credit[$i];
            //$biniyojan_details['debit_credit_type'] = $request->debit_credit_type[$i];
            $biniyojan_details['cash'] = $request->cash[$i];
            $biniyojanDetailsToBeInserted[] = $biniyojan_details;
        }
    }
    if ($biniyojanDetailsToBeInserted) {
        BiniyojanDetails::insert($biniyojanDetailsToBeInserted);
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Inserted');
}
```

Comment: I have tried these both methods but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code create only one row but the noticeable thing is that it create one row but with last data of the array.

Because you are not making object inside the loop it is outside of the loop so the loop runs on the same object and update its properties each time loop runs and save it.

Make object inside the loop so it make new object each time which means it will create new row each time instead of updating the same row.

There is a better way for this if you have same names of your array keys as database table columns.

```
Biniyojan::insert($request->data);
```

It works like this.

```
User::insert([
    ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com'],
    ['name' => 'Marina', 'email' => 'marina@example.com'],
]);
```